# Angularjs creating standalone custom directives

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to modularize my features by components & was wondering is there anyway to include the controller path only in its relevant directives?

i trying to have a folder with structure like this:

```
-app.js
-directives    
--slider
 ---slider.js
 ---slider.html
 ---slider-carousel-controller.js
 ---slider-single-controller.js
```

app.js

```
//require components
require('./directives/banner-slider/banner-slider.js');
```

My custom directive

```
app.directive('bannerSlider', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/directives/banner-slider/banner-slider.html",
    };
}])
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You are never referring a controller path, but the path to the template.

Comment: Can you elaborate the part of your question _to include the controller path only in its relevant directives?_

Comment: i see!  i guess i actually have my thinking just the opposite of referring to the template path rather than controller path. Thx for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

How many relative paths do you plan on having for one directive? Usually, directives are used as a repeatable component with repeating properties that are either inherited from the directives parent scope or it's isolate scope (if you choose to make one).

In your case, it sounds like you might have a directive with multiple properties and depending on those properties you'll be doing x, y and z with them.

IMO I would use an isolate scope and pass in your properties through the directives attributes as models.

```
app.directive('bannerSlider', [function() {
    return {
        scope:{
            property1: "=",
            property2: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/directives/banner-slider/banner-slider.html",
    };
}])
```

This way you're decoupling your dependency on the directives parent scope and using it the way, imo, directives are meant to be used.

And in your html

```
<banner-slider property1="value" property2="value"></banner-slider>
```

Where value is any data that's in the current controller's scope it sits in.

Comment: yes for this case, i have a slider directive which i will be using it repeatedly with different settings & value. isolate scope sounds like a great deal in this situation, i will test this method out & see.
So eventually will all of the different values be placed in the slider.js file? or in something like a main-slider-controller.js?

Comment: none of your values are stored in your directive file (i assume that's your slider.js). They are stored in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible.

Just name your controller (dont forget to call the file where your controller is in your index.html file or whatever)

```
app.directive('bannerSlider', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: "/directives/banner-slider/banner-slider.html",
            controller: 'yourControllerName'

        };
    }])
```